# javascript regex grab variable value

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to grab the value of a variale found in a javascript file. Using xmlhttprequest I can get the page's source, however, I need a regular expression to grab the value of a few variables located within the file.

I want to grab the value of a variable:

```
var VARIABLE_NAME = VALUE
```

I tried this regular expression:

```
/var VARIABLE_NAME \=/
```

But I think I am missing what needs to be done for getting what's after the equal sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
regex = /VARIABLE_NAME=(.*)/;
alert(yourText.match(regex)[1]);
```

Comment: That worked, what's the best way to remove the semi-colon at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a `\` before the `=` sign. You may add also some `\s*` in your Regexp if you're not sure of the number of spaces.

You can see here how to capture a group : [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)